# Upgrading from HBase-1.2.4 to HBase-2.0.0

Tags: hbase

I want to upgrade HBase from **1.2.6** to **2.0.0**. 

Can anybody let me know what's new features I will get in **HBase-2.0.0** from **HBase-1.2.6**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below key features/changes are available in HBase 2.x.

- Coprocessor 2.0 : Coprocessors have changed substantially in 2.0 ranging from top level design changes in class hierarchies
- Ruby 1.8 to Ruby 2.3.3
- Move to slf4j from log4j
- Read and Write paths have undergone significant change, performance re-tuning should be done
- Memstore flush logic modified, this would result in fatter flushes.
- "Master hosting regions" has been marked unsupported
- Prefix tree encoding removed

And lot of API removals and deprecation has been done along with some more changes. You can get the complete list as this [link](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_upgrade_paths).